# find and remove character within label text string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<div class="new">
<label> text text text (=price) </label>
</div>
```

I want to remove the "(=" and ")" around the price,

I've tried the following but to no avail:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery(".new label").each(function() {
         jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace(/[(=]/, ""));
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

I think your regex pattern is off. Try this:

```
jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace(/\(=(.*?)\)/, "$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faq9E/) will match the regexp and replace the content with `price` (in my example, but you could do whatever you want).

Here is the js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery(".new label").each(function() {
         jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace(/\(=([A-z]*)\)/, "$1"));
     });
 });
```

**Explanation**

- The regexp will match every string matching alpha characters (upcase and lower case >> `[A-z]`).
- This string must be surrounded by parenthesis and begin with equal: `\(=` and `/)` (don't forget to escape parenthesis)
- The matched string is used for replacement `$1` (this is the first set between parenthesis `(...)`)

See *Alternation and grouping* paragraph on [this page](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has mentioned the 'g' flag, which will replace everything globally:

```
 $(".new label").each(function() {
   $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/[\)\(=]?/g, ""));
 });
```

You also needed to escape the parentheses.

http://jsfiddle.net/DdbDQ/1/

**edit** I won't delete this answer, but it shouldn't be used, because now that I re-read it, it's obvious that it will replace any parentheses or equals signs in the entire label's text. Use Ben Lee's solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
 jQuery(".new label").each(function() {
     jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace("(=", "").replace(")", ""));         
 });
```

This assumes that (= and ) wont appear anywhere else in the label.

http://jsfiddle.net/HcqQC/